# When is the setup folder created by Magento?

Tags: composer, magento2.2.4, setup

Can I gitignore it in a composer based installation?

I tried deleting vendor/ and composer install, but the setup folder was not newly created.

*EDIT*

It is not happening on each `composer install` - at least not on every run.

In a fresh project I deleted `setup` & `vendor` and called `composer install` -> setup is created. But in another project it's not.

Comment: Alex, setup folder coming when `composer install` run  .it is come from   repo.magento. In my idea you can add setup to gitignore folder

Comment: The question is why this is not in the standard .gitignore of magento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *should* be as part of the composer install, from the `magento/magento2-base` package. If you check inside `{Magento_Root}/vendor/magento/magento2-base` you'll see a rather familiar file structure. This is then just mapped from the composer.json file to the root directory upon install.

Comment: Is there php code which copies those files or does composer do it?

Comment: You are right .. but it seems to need the option         `"magento-force": "override"` to work properly

Comment: Ya, right it mapped  from this package

Comment: True the map is in `vendor/magento/magento2-base/composer.json` what I wonder is where the associated script is defined because it is not in this composer.json

Comment: might be the magento-composer-installer ?